# Tomcat9 Enable Manager Page for multiple services

Tags: linux, tomcat

To enable manager page for some webservice running on port 8999, i have copied the manager directory from webapps to port 8999's appbase i.e., webapps2.

The manager page opens fine on port 8999 but its unable to authenticate with credentials defined in tomcat-users.xml.

Configuration done for service running on 8999.

Tomcat Version  - 9

```
<Service name="Service8999">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
     resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>


      <Connector port="8999" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
             maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
      <SSLHostConfig>
         <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore_new.jks"
                       certificateKeystorePassword='dvjnvjk8d7sv8sd98'/>
      </SSLHostConfig>
  </Connector>

  <Engine name="Service8999" defaultHost="localhost">
          <Host name="localhost" appBase="Service8999"
              unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
               xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
          </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the page doesn't show a HTTP 404 this means the manager page is running and working.

1. Add to your `server.xml` after `<Listener/>` elements and before the `<Service/>` element (copied from the default `apache-tomcat-9.0.20/conf/server.xml`):

   ```
   <GlobalNamingResources>
     <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
          UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
     -->
     <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
               type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
               description="User database that can be updated and saved"
               factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
               pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
   </GlobalNamingResources>
   ```
2. You need to add a user with password and role `manager-gui` to `tomcat-users.xml` for access to the `/manager/html` page.

   A minimalistic sample `tomcat-users.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
                 version="1.0">
     <user username="admin" password="secret" roles="manager-gui"/>
   </tomcat-users>
   ```

   See [Configuring Manager Application Access](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

Answer (score 0):

Your `server.xml` is invalid. You can't nest a `<Realm.../>` inside a `<Service... />`. You can only nest a `<Realm.../>` inside an `<Engine.../>`, `<Host.../>` or `<Context.../>`.